How do I display JSON array contents from OData query
I am trying to craft an OData 4.x query to expand one of my navigation properties that includes several arrays. Here is the query I am using:
http://myHost/odata/myProf?$filter=PM eq 278&$expand=MX1($select=MXDates)
This returns the following data:
{
    "value": [
        {
            "theGUID": "a553fe91-1f23-43f1-be5e-91d94651f087",
            "Table": "myProf",
            "Last": "438bba26-bdce-420b-ba6e-fbc8c5f2d4d9",
            "Next": "438bba26-bdce-420b-ba6e-fbc8c5f2d4d9",
            "PM": 278,
            "MX1": {
                "MXDates": []
            }
        }
    ]
}

I know MXDates contains data because if I look up the exact record in SQL, I find all kinds of details.
Also, if I run a similar query against MX1 directly, and use the $select=* option, I get data from MX1.
Is there a way I can modify my original query so I MX1 shows the contents of the data instead of just []? MXDates is not an expandable property so I can use another $expand.
I have tried adding a ($select=*) to both the MXDates and to MX1 and neither work.

are you using Entity Framework ? If so, please add a tag for it.
